# When I try to push my app to Heroku I get this response:

Tags: heroku

When I try to push my app to Heroku I get this response:

fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.

Comment: Maybe you can show the commands that are you using to deploy.
if you mark the error will be more easy to view too.
You can check the guidelines to make better questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Install heroku CLI plugin
2. Sign in using command heroku login
3. Add heroku as remote repository (gheroku git:remote -a YOUR_PROJECT_NAME)
   Than you can push
   You can find instructions here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: heroku git:remote -a PROJECT_NAME

Answer (score 0):

The **issue** was **caused** due to your project name **used** by another **developer** on heroku remote server. However, you need to change your project name and use the new name to create empty git repository on heroku server by following the command below **before** you **push** your project.

For instance, assumed you have changed your project name and is called foodproject-v2-app-launch

Note that your project name must not more than 30 characters on heroku server and must not be capitalize including special symbol except - and numbers.

Now, go to your terminal and **'cd in'** to your project directory then run the below code.

**Code 1**: $ git init

**Code 2**: $ git add .

**Code 3**: $ git commit -m "Your Initial or Second commit"

**Code 4**: $ heroku create

**Code 5**: $ touch Procfile

Now open your Procfile with editor and add the following code and save it.
**Code**: web: node app.js

**Code 6**: $ git push heroku master

**or**

**Code 6.1**: $ git push heroku main

That should solve the issue mentioned above. Or refer to this article to read more  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: **Please** don't **abuse** formatting **like** this. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and please use it judiciously and semantically.